# Why return db.set(...).then is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Error :

Uncaught Promise Error:  TypeError: db.set(...).then is not a function

Code :

```
const db = require('quick.db')
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const config = require('../config.json');

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

  if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(`:x: test`).setColor("RED"));
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')) return message.channel.send('**:x: test **')

  if (args[0] == 'on') {
     db.set(`oll_${message.guild.id}):`, 'on').then(i => {
      message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription(':white_check_mark:  test').setColor("RANDOM"));
    })
  }
  if (args[0] == 'off') {
    db.set(`oll_${message.guild.id}`, 'off')(i => {
     return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription('** :white_check_mark:  test **').setColor("RANDOM"));
    })
  }



}

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: false,
  permLevel: 3
};

exports.help = {
  name: 'antisp',
  description: 'just test',
  usage: 'antisp <on/off>'
};
```

**discord.js V12**

When I write the command in discord it gives me this error
help please

Comment: Your title is **very** different from your question. (Edit: I've fixed it for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that `db.set` returns a promise (as you're expecting a `then` method on the result). The [documentation](https://quickdb.js.org/docs.html#set-method) doesn't say that it does, and what examples exist there don't show using `then` or show any indication of the work being done asynchronously.

For instance, [this example](https://quickdb.js.org/new-dbtablepass-port.md#table) doesn't have any indication of asynchronous behavior:

```
var economy = new db.table('economy')
economy.set('myBalance', 500) // -> 500
economy.get('myBalance') // -> 500
db.get('myBalance') // -> null
```